How do errors affect gauge detectors in detector error models?
I'm trying to build a detector error model with Stim for a circuit that contains gauge detectors, and I don't quite understand the logic of how errors affect gauge detectors.
My expectation was that since gauge detectors are probabilistic, the outcome would be independent from (Pauli) errors, and that only correlations between gauge detectors would be affected by errors. However, I seem to be wrong, and the output of detector error models seems to further depend on the presence of other detectors.
Here's a simple Bell state preparation example:
circ = stim.Circuit(
    """
    R 0 1
    H 0
    CX 0 1
    X_ERROR(0.01) 0
    M 0 1
    DETECTOR(101) rec[-2]
    DETECTOR(102) rec[-1]
    """)

dem = circ.detector_error_model(
    decompose_errors=False, approximate_disjoint_errors=True,
    allow_gauge_detectors=True)

The detector error model obtained in this case is:
stim.DetectorErrorModel('''
    error(0.01) D0
    error(0.5) D0 D1
    detector(101) D0
    detector(102) D1
''')

My first doubt is this: why the term error(0.01) D0? When we measure qubit 0 the result of it is 0/1 with 50% probability regardless of whether there was an error or not. Of course, the error does change the correlation of the measurements of qubits 0 and 1, but not the value of each one individually. Is it simply because X anticommutes with the MZ measurement?
My main question though is why the following happens. I take the exact same circuit and only remove the second gauge detector (but the measurement stays!):
circ = stim.Circuit(
    """
    R 0 1
    H 0
    CX 0 1
    X_ERROR(0.01) 0
    M 0 1
    DETECTOR(101) rec[-2]
    """)

This is the output:
stim.DetectorErrorModel('''
    error(0.5) D0
    detector(101) D0
''')

Now suddenly the error(0.01) D0 term is gone. The measurements are still correlated though, so I'd have expected the same result as before.
My guess is that this behavior has to do with the fact that in the first example the detector D0 is correlated with D1, whereas in the second example D0 is uncorrelated with any other detector because it's the only one. But I'm not sure this is how it works.
This issue is particularly relevant when considering circuits with conditional logic and active error correction, where we might apply a gate on qubit 1 conditional on the output of the measurement on qubit 0, for which we need to decode the measurement on qubit 0 way before measuring qubit 1.


Now suddenly the error(0.01) D0 term is gone.

It's still there, it was just merged into the 50% gauge error. Errors with the same symptoms combine using Bernoulli addition $p \oplus q = q(1-p) + p(1-q)$. It's still 50% despite the "extra" error being merged into it, because $0.5 \oplus p = 0.5$ for all $p$.
